# Getting LPC coefficient by HTK

Tags: lpc

How can i get lpc coefficient by htk?
I know that there is a binary code "HCopy" which is ganna help with that... but my question is how can i read a wav file in htk?
and i guess i need activeperl to run this? right?
i installed htk but do i need compilation for getting lpc coefficient?
I would appreciate if some one introduce me a pdf or step by step instructions for doing this...
Thanks a million :)

Comment: someone help please????

Comment: For starters: what is htk?

Comment: The Hidden Markov Model Toolkit (HTK) is a portable toolkit for building and manipulating hidden Markov models. HTK is primarily used for speech recognition research although it has been used for numerous other applications including research into speech synthesis, character recognition and DNA sequencing. HTK is in use at hundreds of sites worldwide.

Comment: HTK consists of a set of library modules and tools available in C source form. The tools provide sophisticated facilities for speech analysis, HMM training, testing and results analysis. The software supports HMMs using both continuous density mixture Gaussians and discrete distributions and can be used to build complex HMM systems. The HTK release contains extensive documentation and examples.